# Screen Not Drawing on Remote Desktop Client

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

RDP client is connecting to the server just fine, but only drawing about half of the login screen and then stopping. This is happening on two of my Windows 7 Ultimate boxes, both of which are clean installs. I have three other Windows 7 Ultimate machines that are able to connect just fine, all of these are also clean installs. The only differences that I can find in the setups of the machines is that the ones that don't work properly have multi-core processors and have hardware virtualization support turned on (for XP Mode support in Win 7). I'm using a D-Link WBR-1310 router and having the same issue in both wired and wireless setups. Any help would be awesome. I may even dance.

Comment: @Scott - Your question from SO was automatically migrated over here, so I asked to have them merged. Also, you may want to associate your accounts - go to your profile page and click the Accounts tab. It'll give you a rep boost here.

Comment: please please please don't dance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of variables here..

- Does it happen if you use a crossover ethernet cable to directly connect the two machines, ruling out the existing switch/router and cabling?
- Are there other differences is hardware configuration between the machines? Like video card, ethernet card, etc?
- Have you tried updating the ethernet drivers? Windows 7 drivers are pretty up to date out of the box because the OS is so new, but I've seen really surprising problems from default windows ethernet drivers before.
- Have you tried updating the video drivers? Those are always worth updating because they change so rapidly.

(You could also try using RDP from within a Windows XP VM on the same machine, just for kicks.)

I highly, *highly* doubt this is because the relevant machines are multi-core. I'd personally go on a driver-updating frenzy myself, based on previous experience.

Comment: Previous experiences like this perhaps? :) http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/server-speed-tests

Comment: I gave it a shot, and new network drivers didn't seem to solve the problem.  I upgraded the wired NIC drivers on my desktop and laptop, as well as the wireless drivers on the laptop.  Still having the same issue.

Comment: @scott did you try RDP'ing from the XP VM on the same machine?

Comment: Seems to be working from the XP VM.  Odd.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the problem I've been experiencing (for years, at this point), here are some additional data points:

- It only happens to me when I've got Aero enabled on the remote end. This might explain why you only see it in Windows 7 Ultimate - that's the only version of Windows (other than Enterprise) that allows remote desktop servers to pass Aero.
- On my machines, the problem generally occurs if I scroll in a non-maximized RDP client window. It also happens if I minimize the client window (but not always).

There are two workarounds:

1. Disable Aero. On the RDC client, this means unchecking "Desktop composition" on the Experience tab.
2. If you want Aero enabled, then there's a workaround each time the problem happens. Press Ctrl-Alt-End to get the Windows Security screen on the remote machine. Then hit ESC to exit it. That should "wake up" the remote side.

I really hope MS takes this bug seriously some day and fixes it. Until then, we've got the workarounds listed above.